# Назначение гиперссылок элементам таблицы из базы данных

Tags: php, sql-server

```
<body>
<div class="tutorial">  
<section>
<table class="primer2">
<tr>
<th>Заказчик</th>
<th>Цех-1</th>
<th>Цех-2</th>
<th>Цех-3</th>
</tr>
<?php
include ('inc/kk_conn.inc');
$res="select n, c1, c2, c3 from table";
$zap = sqlsrv_query($conn, $res);
if( $zap === false) {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}
while ($db=sqlsrv_fetch_array($zap))
{
$zak=$db['n'];
$c1=round($db['c1'],3);
$c2=round($db['c2'],3);
$c3=round($db['c3'],3);
echo '<tr>'.
'<td>'.$zak.'</td>';
if($c1>0.949){ 
echo '<td class="condformat1">'.$c1.'</td>';}
else {
echo '<td class="condformat0">'.$c1.'</td>';}
if($c2>0.949){    
echo '<td class="condformat1">'.$c2.'</td>';}
else {
echo '<td class="condformat0">'.$c2.'</td>';}
if($c3>0.949){    
echo '<td class="condformat1">'.$c3.'</td>';}
else {
echo '<td class="condformat0">'.$c3.'</td>';}

echo '</tr>';
}
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
</table>
</section>
</div>
    </body>
```

Есть следующий код, приведенный выше. На выходе получается необходимая таблица. Как каждой ячейке, вновь сформированной таблицы, присвоить еще и соответствующую ей гипперсылку (которая ссылается на подробный отчет по показателю из ячейки). Т.е. у каждой ячейки таблицы своя ссылка.

Comment: структуру б.д. приведите

Answer (score 1):

```
select Заказчик as n, "Цех-1" as c1, "Цех-2" as c2, "Цех-3" as c3, 
from (
SELECT Заказчик, Цех, Коэффициент, Норматив
FROM table1
) up
pivot (avg(Коэффициент) for Цех in ("Цех-1", "Цех-2", "Цех-3")) as pvt
order by Заказчик
```

Получается сводная таблица

Решил проблему с помощью sqlsrv_get_field()